# Expected 5-dimensional input for 5-dimensional weight but got 4

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

RuntimeError: Expected 5-dimensional input for 5-dimensional weight [32, 3, 1, 5, 5], but got 4-dimensional input of size [3, 256, 128, 128] instead

i printed the input shape which is "inputs shape: torch.Size([2, 3, 256, 128, 128])"

The error is occurring when i am training the model  in this line

```
for i, model in enumerate(models):
  opts.append(optim.AdamW(models[i].parameters(), lr=args.lr[i]))
  train_model(models, 
    dataloaders, 
    criterion=loss_fn, 
    optimizers=opts, 
    opath=args.checkpoint_dir, 
    num_epochs=args.epochs)
```

Comment: You should tell us the line on which this happened. Wasn't there a callstack too ?

Comment: thank you for your response its occurred when I am training the model                                    "for i, model in enumerate(models):
        opts.append(optim.AdamW(models[i].parameters(), lr=args.lr[i]))

    train_model(models, dataloaders, criterion=loss_fn, optimizers=opts, opath=args.checkpoint_dir, num_epochs=args.epochs)"  its gives error after first epoch  i also printed the input of my tensor it is "                                                                    
"inputs shape: torch.Size([2, 3, 256, 128, 128])

Answer (score 0):

Your model expect the 5-dimensional input, same with [32,3,1,5,5] shape. But you input the [3,256,128,128] shape. So you must be check your model and fix the input&output shape.

Comment: yes i know that but why its expecting 5 dim as in pyt we generally have 4 dim

Comment: I don't know your model architecture. So you better show your entire code that containing whole architecture and training cycle. Then we can find the problem maybe.